# Comparing doubles' fractions

Tags: java

I'm struggling with the following code which supposed to compare numbers fractions and output some text to user informing him whether the fractions of numbers are the same, i.e.

- User inputs two doubles: **3.14** and **4.14**
- Output: **Fractions are the same**
- User input two double: **3.14** and **4.15**
- Output: **Franctions are not the same**

Somehow I've managed to compile the following code but once I tried to run it in Eclipse IDE I came accross the following notifications:

- Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
- at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
- at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
- at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2456)
- at comparison.main(comparison.java:12)

  ```
    import java.util.Scanner;  
    class comparison
    {
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
          Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
          double a,b; 

          a = scan.nextDouble(); 
          b = scan.nextDouble(); 

          compare(a,b); 
        }

       public static void compare(double n, double m)
       {
          if(n- Math.floor(n) == m - Math.floor(m))
             System.out.println("Fractions are the same"); 
          else
             System.out.println("Fractions are no the same");
       }

      }
  ```

I would love to obtain any proper explanation of my problems, I guess there are variety of different ways to solve this case in different way but can you please stick with my idea and help me out with this ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What numbers did you enter?

Comment: Not addressing your runtime errors, but your algorithm is flawed in that floating-point is not exact, and "equal" numbers will quite often test out as being unequal due to floating-point granularity issues.  You really need to compare the abs of the difference between the two fractions to some "delta" value.

Comment: I think your exception above is simply due to the fact that the "next" value in the input stream cannot be read as a double.

Comment: I did enter the numbers used in given I/O sample, i.e. 3.14 & 4.14

Comment: Well, can't help you any more than that.  I've always avoided the scan functions since they're so fussy.

Comment: So how can fix it to be able to input two doubles at one time ?

Comment: If you are pushing enter in between the numbers, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
Double.toString (n).split ("\\.")[1].equals(Double.toString (m).split ("\\.")[1])
```

but to fix your problem change to

```
a = scan.nextDouble(); 
scan.nextLine ();         // consume CR
b = scan.nextDouble();
```

Comment: thanks a lot (:, but can you see anything that can be wrong in **my code**, I'm really curious where did I messed up...

Comment: After fixing your problem you will still have a problem because double arithmetic is not exact.  You think it is `3.0`, but it could be `3.00000000001`.  If you convert the double to BigDecimal and use `BigDecimal.add` you may have more luck

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for InputMismatchException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html) states:

> Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not
>   match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of
>   range for the expected type.

So, basically, your scanner is trying to get a double, and you apparently entered something that either was not a double or was out of the range of a double.

The best way to handle this would probably be to get Strings from the scanner, and then check to see if they can be converted to doubles. Output an error message if not.

Edit - in agreement with @scary-wombat - use BigDecimal - it has a constructor that takes a String. Be sure to catch NumberFormatException, which will be thrown if what you enter cannot be converted.